# How do I loop through a method x amount of times?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have this project with a method like so.

```
private void LoopThis()
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

And I have this button that invokes the method, and a textbox where I enter a int let's say i enter 10.

Ten I want that method to execute 10 times.

What kind of loop do I use to do this?

Comment: You should really read a book or a very basic tutorial, asking trivial question in StackOverflow is a waste of time.

Comment: What is your problem here? Do you know about for...loop? Or are you asking how to retrieve the content of a textbox and transform it in an integer?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   int times;

   if (Int32.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out times))
   {
       // It could parse the input text (so we deduce it was an integer)
       // and not a string.

       for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
       {
           LoopThis();
       }
   }
   else
   {
      // Throw exception or show a message to the user
   }
}
```

Comment: What if you type "ABC" instead of an integer?

Comment: Then I just throw an exception with a messagebox.

Comment: @Steve I have updated the code to use `TryParse` in case the conversion fails.